# Django select related of select related

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a *Student* model which has a foreign key to a *School* model (related name is `school`) which has itself a FK to a *Country* model (related name is `country`).

I want to select the *Student* along with its school and country.
Do I need to write this:

```py
student = Student.objects.filter(pk=123).select_related("school", "school__country").first()
student.school # use object cache
student.school.country # use object cache
```

or is this enough:

```py
student = Student.objects.filter(pk=123).select_related("school__country").first()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the `school__country` version implies that `school` will also need to be selected.

Comment: Yes in fact it was explained here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related where it is written what does or does not hit the database